# react-native deep linking while app is running in the background

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I have my android app (react-native based) and the deep link first time when I run it while the app is not running in the background works great, but when the app runs in the background and i click on the deep-link it doesn't even open the app ... I'm not sure even where to start with this bug I tried a few `console.logs` in lifecycle events but they don't even run.

please guide me where should I look for the issue and how to fix it, thanks!

Comment: I face same issue. Did you get workaround yet?

Comment: Did you add Linking.removeEventListener("url", this.handleOpenURL), function at componentWillUnmount()? Can you remove ti and try again?

Comment: I face same issue to, have you find the solution for this?

Comment: Please check the below link for a simple solution;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62693760/react-native-deep-linking-is-not-working-when-app-is-not-in-background-androi/63897179#63897179

Answer (score 2):

The deep linking is working as expected for me even the app is in `background`. Please check the below specifications.

> Node Version : v12.18.x **OR Greater**
> NPM Version : v6.14.x **OR Greater**
> react-native-cli : 2.0.1
> react-native : 0.63.x **OR Greater**

Please check if you have added below line in your `AppDelegate.m`.

> #import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

It must be added above `#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED` line. Adding it below this line will cause failing of build while Archiving it for release.

Please check if you have added below code in your `AppDelegate.m` which is responsible for deep linking.

> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
> openURL:(NSURL *)url
> options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
> {
> return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
> }

It will work for app cold boot, but it will not work if your app is in `background`. For this, you need to add below code in your `AppDelegate.m`

> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id> *_Nullable))restorationHandler {
> return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
> continueUserActivity:userActivity
> restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
> }

This should work irrespective of your AppState: `active **OR** background`.

This worked for me as expected! Give it a try. This is should definitely work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks. `application continueUserActivity` did the trick for iOS

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount() {
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this._handleDeepLinkingURL);
    this._handleDeepLinkingURL(); /* Invoking method manually on launching app very first time */
},
componentWillUnmount() {
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', this._handleDeepLinkingURL);
},
_handleDeepLinkingURL(event) {
    /*
    console.log(event.url);
    event.url will hold the url of the app if the app launched when its running in background

    event param will be undefined when the app launched from kill state or first time
    */
    Linking.getInitialURL()
    .then(url => {
        if (url && url.indexOf("?params=") !== -1) {
            const paramsString = url.substr(
                url.indexOf("?params=") + 8
            );
            alert('paramsString is : ' + paramsString);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Please try and add a little detail about what your code does and how it solves the problem. It will help everyone else in future.

Comment: Please check the below link for a simple solution;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62693760/react-native-deep-linking-is-not-working-when-app-is-not-in-background-androi/63897179#63897179