# React Native - Deep linking is not working when app is not in background (Android, iOS)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, deep-linking

- if app in background

  > specific screen will open.
- if app is not in background or kill the app

  > it will show first screen only.

> Linking.getInitialURL() is return null

Comment: you got any solution for this ? I am getting the same issue ?

Comment: @PankajNegi try below solution is works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want to do redirection in case of the app is kill or not yet launch, find the below simple solution:**

```
// Don't forget to import 

    import {
      Linking
    } from 'react-native';



  useEffect(() => {
    const getAsyncURL = async () => {
      const initialUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL();
      if (initialUrl != undefined && initialUrl != null){
         // Handle initialURL as per your response and open a specific screen using navigation
      }
    };

    getAsyncURL();
  }, []);
```

**// The above solution is work for me*

Comment: this one was super helpful, thanks for posting!